# UICollectionView: issue many cells are selected when I only select one cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I faced an issue an take lot of time but cannot figure out the issue:

I created a UICollectionView with very simple content, one lable to indicate cell_number, and  when a cell is selected, the background of cell is changed to orange. 
I create a custom cell with xib file for design (very simple one). And I load this cell from my UICollectionView in my DemoUICVViewController.m file normally as many people did with some steps like:
- declare the custom cell class in ViewDidload:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];`
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyCustomCell * myCell = (MyCustomCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
myCell.lable.text = [arrayNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
return myCell; 
}
```

and when selected:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Get the cellForItemAtIndexPath and set the background coler of cell to orange
}`
```

Number of section I return 1, and number of item in section I return 10

All the cells in UICollectionView are display correctly. But when I tap to select a cell I see not only that cell is orange, but also some other cells also change to orange for e.g cell 5 and cell 9. 
I debug but the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` only get called once and at the right index, very strange when some other cells also be orange. 
I am not sure if the problem is of Reusability of cell identifier, could someone give me some advise.

I attached photo for e.g here:
[Image describes](http://i62.tinypic.com/35ann8l.png)

Comment: This is because of cell reuse. There are many answers on SO about that, so do some searching.

Comment: @rdelmar: I searched but still not found the clear idea, why the orange appears for other cells.I found one similar question but no clear anwser enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446070/add-checkmark-image-in-cell-in-collectionview-issue-ios

Comment: You seem to be registering one class (MyCustomCell) but casting the dequeued cell as another class (myCell).  Also, your reuse identifier is MyCell when registered but myCell when dequeuing.  Are these typos in your question or in your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the root cause to fix: add this line to check to

```
collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
```

...

```
if(myCell.selected)
    // set background of cell to orange;
else
    // set white background;
```

...
}